# How to check if an object is a regular object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object, prototype, proto

I have a created [a merging library](https://github.com/mesqueeb/merge-anything) that merges objects recursively. Sometimes in the middle there would be an object that is actually a special class (like the [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#constructor_1) of Firestore).

In my merging function I check if something is an object or not like so:

```
function isObject (payload) {
  const getType = Object.prototype.toString.call(payload).slice(8, -1)
  return getType === 'Object'
}
```

However, with this check some special classes with special prototypes are still considered to be regular JavaScript objects.

**My problem:**
 The object will loose its special class prototype because I only go through the non-prototype values to recursively merge.

**My question:**
 How can I change the function above to not only check if it's a JavaScript object, but also check if it's a **regular JavaScript object**?

Basically I only wanna return `true` on `isObject(obj)` if `obj` is an object like so: `{}` or with any props.

But once the prototype is different (and thus it's a special class), then I want to return `false` on `isObject(obj)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to checking the prototype, you can check if its `constructor` is `Object`:

```js
const isPlainObject = obj => obj.constructor === Object && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype;

const obj1 = { foo: 'bar' };
const obj2 = new Date();
const obj3 = [];
[obj1, obj2, obj3].forEach(obj => console.log(isPlainObject(obj)));
```

Note that using `getPrototypeOf` and checking that it is `===` to `Object.prototype` is more reliable than using `toString` - `toString` may return anything, after all.

If you're going to possibly pass something that's null or undefined to `isPlainObject`, then of course include a check to see that the `obj` is truthy before trying to access properties on it:

```js
const isPlainObject = obj => obj && obj.constructor === Object && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype;

const obj1 = { foo: 'bar' };
const obj2 = new Date();
const obj3 = [];
[obj1, obj2, obj3].forEach(obj => console.log(isPlainObject(obj)));
```

Comment: gotta modify your answer a little bit because `obj` can be `null`:
`const isPlainObject = obj => obj && obj.constructor === Object && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype;`

Answer (score 0):

it can be tricky as some javascript types have a `typeof` "object" like below

```
console.log(typeof []) // object
console.log(typeof null) // object
```

A simple way to check for a plain Object is to utilize Object's `toString` method and also validate for `null` like this

```
/**@return boolean */
function isObject(val) {
   const _toString = Object.prototype.toString;
   return val !== null && _toString.call(val) === '[object Object]';
}
```

now we test this

```
isObject({}); // true
isObject({a: 2, b: 3}); // true
isObject(null); // false
isObject([]); // false
isObject(new Object()); // true
isObject(new Array()); // false
```